# Sharing Boolean between processes

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, audio, multiprocessing

I’m looking to share a bool value between two processes in Python. I have a queue which I would like to initialize by letting it fill up on the first run of a while loop. After this, the bool is set to true and the other process can now begin reading from the queue.

NOTE: I’ve tried using value but the bool won’t update. Do I need to pass the bool as an arg to the process in order for this to work?

Also, here is my code:

```
#Main thread
bool_val = Value(“i”, 0)

#queue gets written to...

bool_val = Value(“i”, 1)
```

```
#other thread
If bool(bool_val) is True:
    #read from queue
```

Comment: Please show us the code which you have tried.  That way it will be much easier to say what else is needed.

Comment: Added to question

Comment: Yes, you do need to pass `bool_val` to the function that you are parallel-processing

Answer (score 6):

If you rely on using [multiprocessing.Value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) - that object itself can be accessed via the `value` attribute.

Here's a primitive example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Queue, cpu_count, current_process


def handle(v):
    val = v.value
    if bool(val) is True:
        print('process {} is using value {}'.format(current_process().name, val))
    else:
        v.value = 1
        print('process {} changed value {} to {}'
              .format(current_process().name, val, v.value))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = Value('i', 0)

    processes = [Process(target=handle, args=(v,)) for _ in range(cpu_count())]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    print(v, v.value)
```

The output:

```
process Process-1 changed value 0 to 1
process Process-2 is using value 1
process Process-3 is using value 1
process Process-4 is using value 1
process Process-5 is using value 1
process Process-6 is using value 1
process Process-7 is using value 1
process Process-8 is using value 1
process Process-9 is using value 1
process Process-10 is using value 1
process Process-11 is using value 1
process Process-12 is using value 1
<Synchronized wrapper for c_int(1)> 1
```