# Python multiprocesses - variable states does not seem to be shared within processes

Tags: python, bots, python-multiprocessing, pyautogui

I've been trying to make a gamebot but whenever I try to change my variable `run` in the function `clickClaim()` it does not seem to affect it in the `mainScript()` function.

Below my code:

```
run = True

#Claim loot 
def clickClaim():
    global run
    while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
        if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("Images/cl.png",confidence=.8):
            run = False
            sc.sac("Images/cl.png",0.1)
            pyautogui.click(960,500)
            pyautogui.click(960,500)
            run = True

#Perform click while "run" variable is True
def mainScript():
    clicked = False
    while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
        global run
        if run == True and clicked == False:
            pyautogui.mouseDown(1200,500)
            print("Mouse is Down")
            clicked = True
        elif run == False and clicked == True:
            pyautogui.mouseUp()
            print("Mouse Is Up")
            clicked = False

mainS = multiprocessing.Process(target=mainScript)
bgClaim = multiprocessing.Process(target=clickClaim)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bgClaim.start()
    mainS.start()
```

I'm just starting with Python so most likely this code is really poor and there's definetely another more optimal way to achieve my goal but my main question here is why does the variable does not seem to change.

I tried making the variable global and to achieve my goal in another way. Maybe multiprocessing is not the way to achieve what I want?

Comment: In `multiprocessing` all your variables will be in different processes, so global variables like `run` are no longer global.

Comment: The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56549971/sharing-boolean-between-processes) may help.

Comment: You can share variables between processes but you need to use `multiprocessing.Value` or `multiprocessing.Array` to do so. Check the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

Comment: wow guys, you're too fast :D Thank you, I was indeed not aware of that and it explains a lot. I instead trying to solve this with threading, still don't know if that's the optimal way of achieving my goal but looks like the variables are being shared there.